# Why Google Webfontloader no works?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I wanna to use google webfontloader to load web font async
Here is my code:

```
<script>
        WebFontConfig = {
            custom: {
                families: [
                    'Noto Sans SC Sliced',
                    'Changa'
                ],
                urls: [
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa',
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosansscsliced.css'
                ]
            },
            timeout: 5000
        };
</script>
<script src='/lib/webfontloader.js'></script>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        font-family: 'Noto Sans SC Sliced', sans-serif;
    }

#Logo {
    font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
}
```

The browser report no error and the font never change.What is wrong with my code?

Would you please help me?Thank you.

ps:I downloaded the webfontloader.js from here:https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader .The link is from google which showed in this page:https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jess Kenney said,I should use WebFont.Load() instead.

Here is code which is correct:

```
<script>
        WebFont.load({
            google: {
                families: ['Noto Sans SC Sliced',
                    'Changa'],
                urls: [
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa',
                    'https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosansscsliced.css'
                ]
            }
        });
</script>
<script src='/lib/webfontloader.js'></script>
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        font-family: 'Noto Sans SC Sliced', sans-serif;
    }

#Logo {
        font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Lastly,thanks @Jess Kenney's help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Web Font Loader getting started guide](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader#get-started), it looks like you have to call `WebFont.load()` after you define the config in order to actually load the fonts.

Comment: So strange that the browser report an error 'WebFontConfig.Load is not a function'.

Comment: I doubt if two js is different,but after I replaced my js of the one you showed,the problem still here.

Comment: You have to call WebFont.load() after you include the webfontloader.js file.

Comment: OK,now it works.Let me answer this question to help any other also need this.